# How to read from a file I already wrote in it using Java

Tags: java

I just wrote to a file using

```
FileWriter fWrite=new FileWriter("C:/folder/DP.txt");
BufferedWriter output =  new BufferedWriter(fWrite);
int  lastItem = splitItems(capacity); //** calling the function that returns the last item in the file
output.close();
```

Then I closed the file and also made sure the data has been written on it. In another function, I will need to read the data that I just wrote. I write the following code:

```
 public static int splitItems(int capacity) throws IOException //read items from the file
{
     BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/folder/DP.txt"));

    //read the last line from file
    String tmp, strLine = null;
     while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
       strLine = tmp;
    } //end while

     String lastLine = strLine; //save the last line

     String[] split = lastLine.split("\\s+"); /** split based on spaces
     int lastItem=Integer.parseInt(split[capacity]); //save the int in the file
     br.close();  //closing the file
     return lastItem; //return the last number

}//end split items
```

Then, in the run, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And when I check the file, I find it empty. What is the problem. Why the `BufferedReader` delete the file content ?

**EDIT:** I added more detailed code. I can not post it all. It is quite long code. The main idea is that: Everything was fine. The data written to the file correctly. When I added a new function that needs to read from the file, I got the error. In the above code, I added a ** comment in the line that the compiler gave error.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the *complete* error message. You have left out information that is necessary for us to help you.

Comment: Which line do you get the NullPointerException? Are you sure the file had data before reading it? (Did you open the folder from the OS  to see its contents)

Comment: It works fine for me... Please add [sscce](http://sscce.org) - code that can be used to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to close your BufferedWriter. Then you can read the file and you will get your written content. An example of the writer is [here](http://www.javadb.com/write-to-file-using-bufferedwriter)

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library instead of coding it your self, look at FileUtils class in Apache Commons IO http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

It is tried and tested